# Invalid property 'durability' of bean class [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-4

I am upgrading Spring from Spring 2.x to Spring 4.2.4 and Quartz from 1.8 to 2.3

Following bean throws "Invalid property 'durability' of bean class [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]"

If I remove the durability property, I get "org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be durable"

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="durability" value="true"/>
         <property name="recover" value="false"/>
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="deleteTempFileJobScheduler" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="deleteTempFileJobSchedulerTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Quartz-Job has a attribute called durability.

This property determines whether a Job without triggers should automatically deleted.

I.e. if you set

```
 <property name="durability" value="true"/>
```

than Jobs remain in the JobStore even if no triggers point to it anymore.

But if you set

```
<property name="durability" value="false"/>
```

than jobs should be removed from the JobStore if no triggers point to it.
In that case Quartz gives you the mentioned Exception if you try to add a Job without Triggers to the JobStore (since you add a Job which will be immediately removed).

To prevent such an Exception you could add a Job together with an Trigger to the JobStore.

Comment: `you could add a Job together with an Trigger to the JobStore.`, Any example about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need set `durability` property to [`JobDetailFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/JobDetailFactoryBean.html)
(in your case, this is `deleteTempFileJobScheduler`) and not to [`SchedulerFactoryBeam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html)

Answer (score 0):

When we are creating job itself , you can add **storeDurably(true)**
. It is work for me .

```
 JobDetail job = newJob(JobScheduler.class)
                    .withIdentity( sc.getId()+ "_Job")
                    .usingJobData(getJobDataMap(sc))
                    .storeDurably(true)
                    .build();
```